# How to use a like function to get the data having comma

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv-simple

We have a data like below

```
Column1,|Column2,|Col|Abc|Column3,&TableName --- ( Here my delimiter is "&" )
```

Is there any way i can make an output as below

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,&TableName
```

For the first column has data  ---

```
Column1,|Column2,|Col|Abc|Column3,
```

Wherever we have "," along with the value , those values we need to fetch and concantenate..

Final output for the first field  should look like

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,
```

Any suggestions.. pleasse .. ( Please let me know if my question is not clear )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that's what you're looking for, but

```
sed 's/[^,]*|//g' < input.csv > output.csv
```

Would produce your expected output on your sample input record.

It essentially removes everything up to and including the right-most `|` character in each `,`-separated field.